# How do I integrate $\frac{1}{x}$ when $x$ has a power?

Tags: integration

As the title says, how would I integrate $\frac {1}{x^2}$?

I know that $\frac {1}{x}$ integrates to $\ln x$ but I am unsure when $x$ has a power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{1}{x^n} = x^{-n}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I got x^-2  -> integration:  -x^-1 = -1/x, would you agree with this answer or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Aside from the constant of integration, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

For $a\ne-1,\quad\int x^adx=\frac1{a+1}x^{a+1}+C$